# serverless update check failed error

Tags: kali-linux, node.js, npm

I want to intsall serverless on my kali linux . In order to proceed for serverless installalation we need node js install , which i have already done .

```
root@gpunk:~# npm --version
3.10.10
root@gpunk:~# node --version
v6.10.0
root@gpunk:~# nvm --version
0.31.0
```

(Some solutions on github suggested to install node js by nvm to solve this issue , tried that as well..) . now when i run the command to npm install -g serverless to install serverless , i get following error message .

```
root@gpunk:~# npm install -g serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/serverless -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/slss -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/sls -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless

> serverless@1.24.1 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib/node_modules/serverless
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js


┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│          serverless update check failed           │
│        Try running with sudo or get access        │
│       to the local update config store via        │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /root/.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/lib
`-- serverless@1.24.1
```

What possible mistake am i making , and how to overcome it ??

Comment: Have you run the command prefixed with sudo?

Comment: i am in root right now so i don't need to use sudo , right ?? by the way when i try to use sudo it shows invalid command..

Comment: See this [bug report](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4452). Things ought to work if you do the installation as a user other than root.